# Excel Lookup value spans across rows and columns

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I have some data in one sheet 1 that has the Pupil Name and some other pupil related data.

For example:

```
Pupil Name
Joe Bloggs
Terry Jones
Peter Smith
John Doe
Lenny Peter
Harry Potter
```

In another sheet (sheet 2) a list of teachers and the corresponding pupils they will be conducting the interview with. Each teacher will have upto 6 interviews and these are in columns Candidate 1 to Candidate 6.

For example

```
Teacher, Candidate 1, Candidate 2, Candidate 3, Candidate 4, Candidate 5, Candidate 6
Mrs Smith, Joe Bloggs, Terry Jones, Peter Smith, John Doe, Lenny Peter, Harry Potter
```

In sheet 1, I would like to bring back the name of the interviewer back into the pupil sheet. I've tried INDEX and Match by even adding the column headers in the column match but this only brings back those interviewers in the Candidate 1 column and not the other 5 columns. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Please put a screenshot of second sheet data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need something like the following in `B2`:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A$2:A$100,SUMPRODUCT((Sheet2!B$2:G$100=A2)*(ROW(B$2:G$100)))-1)
```

Obivously the `100` needs to be swapped with a rownumber that your data on `Sheet2` ends.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HLOOKUP.

Here is my take on the issue [Example worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN4WR.png)

I used the following formula in the second column =+HLOOKUP(A2;$E$2:$K$3;2;0)

Comment: Thanks qwerty1 but this wouldn't work just like the Index and Match didn't as I needed to match across columns and rows.